# Does there exist an inclusion map making a given boundary point into an interior point?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Every smooth manifold is assumed to be Hausdorff and second-countable.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with nonempty boundary.

$\forall p\in \partial M$, does there exist a smooth manifold $N$ with or without boundary such that $M\subset N$ is an embedded submanifold with boundary, $M$ has the same dimension as $N$, and $p$ is an interior point of $N$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think there exists $N$ satisfying the conditions.

Comment: OK, then try to prove it, starting with the case where $M=[0,1)\times R^n$, and explain where did you get stuck. I also suggest doing this first for topological manifolds.